# Top View Controller not showing up when using swift google signin

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to set up google sign-in set up following a tutorial for my app. But I don't get a response when I clicked on the google sign-in button and kept getting the below error when I click the button again. I am not sure why doesn't the top view controller show up and why I get the error - is there something wrong with the view controller function?

`Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled the sign-in flow.}`

I've followed the steps to setting up SDK, adding GIDClient to target project, reverse ClientID to URL and GoogleService.plist copied to project repo.

After that I've implemented the below:

in LoginView

```
@MainActor
final class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController{
            guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
                return.init()
            }
            guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
                return.init()
            }
            return root
        }
    func signInWithGoogle() async throws {
        let topVc = getRootViewController()
                
            let gidSignInResult = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: topVc)
            
            guard let idToken: String = gidSignInResult.user.idToken?.tokenString else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            let accessToken: String = gidSignInResult.user.accessToken.tokenString
            
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)
        
//        let authDataResult = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
        print(credential)
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @Binding var username: String
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    @State var errorMessage = ""
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("DarkGreen").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            HStack(spacing: 70) {
                GoogleSignInButton(viewModel: GoogleSignInButtonViewModel(scheme: .dark, style: .icon, state:.normal)) {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            try await viewModel.signInWithGoogle()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
```

In Utilities,

```
import UIKit

final class Utilities {
    
    static let shared = Utilities()
    private init() {}
    
    @MainActor
    func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
        let controller = controller ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because using that root view controller method is not very SwiftUI like, you should use a UIViewControllerRepresentable

Comment: Note, there is no need for `AuthenticationViewModel` to be `ObservableObject`, you are not publishing anything from it.
 I suspect your `GoogleSignInButtonViewModel` is also a `ObservableObject`, so you are creating a new instance every time. Don't know why you show the code for `Utilities`, you never use it in the code that you show.
You seem to be mixing UIKit and SwiftUI concepts the wrong way.
Read the basics of SwiftUI again, and have a look at this **official** link:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)